# How to compute raw vertex data transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, rotations, programming

This question has coding components to it, but mostly it's just a math question.

In C++ using OpenGL, I have a system set up where you can easily add vertices to a single buffer and draw them. The main issue with this is that I can't easily change the model matrix in order to rotate these vertices. I thought the approach that would be the best for performance would be to manually rotate the vertices before they go into a buffer. The problem is, I don't know how to go about doing this.

Right now, I have a cube class that takes a position, size, and rotation. Currently, it computes the 8 vertices by taking the position +/- size / 2. This gets a Minecraft like cube. I would've assumed I could rotate this cube doing something as simple as position.x + (size.x / 2 * sin(rotation.x)), but this hasn't seemed to work. I'm assuming there is a much more elegant approach to this.

I've seen many questions similar to this, but they all use immediate mode OpenGL, where you can specify things like glRotatef() and it does all the work for you.

Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks.

[How I am currently computing the vertices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEnSr.png)

Comment: A single angle is enough in 2D, but in 3D, you need in all generality **three** angles to define a rotation.

Comment: @JeanMarie That was just an example for computing the rotation of the x components. The example does not work for the x components, however. I'm not exactly sure why but it simply makes the cube smaller in the x axis.

Comment: Even for the change in the $x$ component, the 3 angles are likely to intervene.

Comment: Either you use 3 angles (yaw,pitch,roll or Euler angles) or you take a single angle + the axis of rotations (whose unit axis depends on 2 parameters,  making again 3 parameters. In this case, see the Rodrigues formula or one of its avatars on Wikipedia.

Comment: @JeanMarie Forgive my lack of math knowledge, but I'm not 100% sure what you mean by this. Shouldn't each transformation on each axis be independent of one another?

Comment: I forgive it ! Working with 3D Rotations can generate a lot of headaches ! Beware of considering a general 3D rotation as a combination of the 3 rotations $R_x$ followed by $R_y$ followed by $R_z$ ; if you use Euler angles for example, it's $R_z$ followed by $R_x$ followed (anew!) by $\color{red}{R_z}$ !

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks, I think I'm on the right track now. I'm a newbie so I can't upvote or anything.